# How to count the number of rows in an Excel document in xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlsxwriter

does anyone know how to count the number of rows on an Excel worksheet using xlsxwriter? I have looked for a method similar to XLRD's worksheet.nrows in xlsxwriter but have not been able to find one. I had orginally tried to use both xlsxwriter and xlrd in a script but I have errors due to what I think is a problem with both xlsxwriter and xlrd trying to open the same file at the same time. I can attach the code if that would help. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What are the errors you get ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xlsxwriter` does not support reading from a workbook. It is designed to create excel workbooks.

From their site: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html

> It cannot read or modify existing Excel XLSX files.

Comment: Hi, thank you. That would explain why I could not find anything on it. Do you have any ideas you could create/write a new Excel file with with xlsxwriter but before you close the xlsxwriter document use xlrd to open the document to read the number of rows? I keep getting an error in which the xlrd reference to the Excel file believes the file is not there, even though it is. Thank you.

Comment: @user3688163 If you haven't closed the writer, there is no guarantee that your file has been saved to disk. Indeed, if I sleep for 5 seconds after I finish writing and before reading, the book is not there.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here - if you're trying to find out how many rows are in the spreadsheet you're creating with xlwt, you can check the `last_used_row` attribute on the worksheet object. But it seems odd that you would have to do so, given that you have to set the row number when writing to the spreadsheet in the first place.